# Indexing a `numpy.array` with a `dask.array`

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, dask

I am getting errors when indexing a `numpy.array` with a `dask.array`, I'm not sure whether this is a feature or a bug.

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: import dask.array as dka
In [3]: foo = np.arange(10)
In [4]: bar = np.arange(3)

In [5]: foo[bar]
Out[5]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [6]: foo[dka.from_array(bar)]
<ipython-input-16-9c4b06c0d0c4>:1: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  foo[dka.from_array(bar)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-9c4b06c0d0c4> in <module>
----> 1 foo[dka.from_array(bar)]

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 3 were indexed
```

I am using versions `dask==2022.01.0` and `numpy==1.22.0`.

Comment: Display `dka.from_array(bar)`.  And `np.array(dka.from_array(bar))`.

Comment: what do you mean? everything is defined in the snippet

Comment: jeez. fwiw it's not at all clear to me what you're aiming at with your first comment either @hpaulj - the OP clearly understands the difference between dask and numpy arrays. full MRE, tough/confusing problem the OP clearly put effort into, version info, well-thought out question... +1 from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as the error says (albeit in a not-so-clear way), is that numpy doesn't recognize dask arrays as a supported type, but does recognize them as a sequence, and so is interpreting your indexing operation as an attempt to do multidimensional indexing.

If you make it clear that you're trying to provide an array of indices into the first dimension, this works just fine:

```py
In [5]: foo[dka.from_array(bar), ...]
Out[5]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

or equivalently, you could use [`np.take`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html#numpy.take) or any of a number of indexing options:

```py
In [6]: np.take(foo, dka.from_array(bar), axis=0)
Out[6]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

Comment: thanks for your kind answer :) I am surprised `dask` arrays are not supported by `numpy`, for example I see that `foo[pd.Series([0])` works just fine, which means `numpy` and (just to name another package) `pandas` can "talk to each other"

Comment: Note though that when you do this, the result is not a dask array. You’re converting the array to numpy. It makes sense you can’t really use a dask array to index a numpy array because the form of the result would not be known until the indexer is computed.

Comment: shouldn't the form/shape of the result depend solely on the indexer's shape, not its values?

Comment: I think you're right. however, when indexing a numpy array you always get a numpy array back. `np.array([1, 2, 3])[pd.Series([0, 0])]` could in a parallel pydata universe return a series with index [0, 1] and values [1, 1], but it doesn't. you also don't get a dask array when you index a numpy array with dask.